# Existence of Real-Time Multiprocessor Schedule

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, scheduling, process-scheduling

Does an algorithm exist to check for the existence of a Real-Time Multiprocessor Schedule for aperiodic hard tasks(all of which have the same Release time)?

Assumptions:

- The processors are Uniform parallel machines
- Job preemption is permitted
- Job migration is permitted
- Job parallelism is forbidden

EDIT: Let there be $n$ jobs $J = \{j_1, j_2,\text{...}, j_n\}$ and $m$ no of processors $P = \{p_1, p_2,\text{...}, p_m\}$. Each job $j_i$ has a task time $t_i$(amount of work it would take to complete it) and due time $d_i$. Each processor has a constant speed $s_i$(amount of work it does per unit time). Each task must be completed before its due time.

I am interested to know about an algorithm with can check feasibility of a schedule in polynomial time.

Comment: An algorithm probably exists – I suspect you're interested in an *efficient* algorithm.

Comment: Can you specify your problem in more details?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I added some more details. Let me know if you want me to clarify more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Y. Cho and S. Sahni, Scheduling Independent tasks with due times on a uniform Processor System, Jr. of the ACM, 1980](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322047.322055)

Presents an algorithm to preemptively schedule **n** tasks(with due dates) on **m** uniform processors whenever a solution exists in $O(n\log{n} + mn)$ time.

Which is a stronger problem than I wanted to solve but still gives a polynomial algorithm, which answers my question.